# Are there languages which use  the negation of  'odd' to denote 'even'?

Tags: linguistic-universals, cross-linguistic, lexical-semantics, vocabulary

This question is influenced by another one I found on the German SE, "[Warum nennt man in Deutsch die Zahlen 0, 2, 4 … “gerade” Zahlen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2744/warum-nennt-man-in-deutsch-die-zahlen-0-2-4-gerade-zahlen)". It asks "Why call Germans the numbers 0, 2, 2 "even".

The following languages have these pairs:

- German: **gerade** — **ungerade**;
- Italian: **pari** — **dispari**;
- Portuguese: **par** — **Ímpar**;
- Spanish: **par** — **impar**;
- Russian: **чётное** — **нечётное**.

Note that for all of them 'even' is expressed by the basic form and 'odd' is derived from that form.

Other languages like  English use different words **even** and **odd**.

**Edit:**

I modified the question in reaction to the comments to reduce the number of possible results.

> Are there languages where **odd**  is expressed by the basic term and
>   **even**  is derived from that?

Comment: There are over 6,000 human languages currently spoken - you may want to reword the title of this question, unless you really want a list.

Comment: @bernd_k I took the liberty to change the formatting of your question. I think the sense is the same. If you want to further improve it, you're obviously free to do so. :) A note: if you can provide a rough translation of that linked question, it would be really nice! :)

Comment: Note that in English we do have the word _uneven_, which, while not being completely interchangeable with _odd_, can be used in a lot of the same environments: "They added a chair at the end of the table because we had an *uneven* number of people in our party."

Comment: Still, this question will generate a list which probably will not be useful

Comment: Yet another question that while people object to it here would be fine on the proposed languages.SE site.

Comment: The question asks whether some language (with some properties) exist. I cannot see how a list would answer it logically. If such a language exists, the answer “Yes, Syldavian has this property.” would be definitive. If no such language exists, the problem is that we might never get an answer. (An intermediate option would be “This question is addressed in this paper of the Syldavian Society of Linguistics; they say they couldn't find any such language and they have a tentative explanation of that phenomenon. Such an answer would be very interesting.)

Comment: Danish: lige - ulige

Comment: Languages tend to use
even-uneven (=odd)
all your examples do that, additionally Hungarian:
páros-páratlan

Comment: @JPP The problem is that only one answer may be accepted, and if there are multiple "correct" answers then accepting any one would be arbitrary. The *best* answer would not be simply a citation of a single language, but a link to research and a discussion of the applicability of that research.

Comment: @MarkBeadles Correct. Although the part where JPP says that "this paper says there isn't such a language" is a good answer too. As long as they are not link-only answers or very poor answers, any "answer" is OK (i.e. be it negative or positive about the results).

Answer (score 7):

I think your question may reflect an instance of a much more general pattern. That is, suppose you find an expression X in a language, and another expression Y in that language, and you believe X and Y to stand in a "privileged" relation (two types elaborated below). It seems that, across languages, one is likely to find that X and Y occur as simplex (i.e., nondecomposable) lexical items asymmetrically: i.e., if Y occurs as a simplex lexical item in the language, so does X. But simplex X occurring in a language does not guarantee expression of simplex Y.

One concrete example to explain one notion of a "privileged" relation between two expressions is privileged antonymy. Consider the adjectives *tall* and *short*: we "feel" that these expressions are related in a way that makes the inferences in (1) and (2) valid, but not that in (3) (despite *long* on occasion meaning something very similar to *tall*):

1. Mary is taller than John |= John is shorter than Mary
2. Mary is shorter than John |= John is taller than Mary
3. Mary is longer than John !|= John is shorter than Mary   (where !|= reads as "does not entail")

Given what was discussed in the first paragraph above, we thus expect a language to exist where there is no word for *short*, but that conveys such a meaning via negating the positive adjective, e.g. *not tall*. One never expects to find a language that does the reverse, e.g. where *short* occurs with *not short*, and expression of simplex *tall* fails to occur.

Describing strong versus weak meanings, Larry Horn in his 1972 dissertation gives nice examples using the dual modals *must* and *may*, and adjectives like *(un)able* and *(im)possible*, to observe that in general, it seems the "positive" or "stronger" of a dual occurs as an expression *simpliciter*, while the "negative" or "weaker" is likely to occur as a combination of the positive/stronger expression with a negative marker. Note that such a synthetic construction carries exactly the (logical) meaning of what the negative/weaker expression as a simplex lexical item would carry.

Horn has some speculations about why this asymmetric pattern may obtain, but it has not so far been explained in detail, and how far such phenomena extend throughout lexical semantics is (I think) unknown. Understanding that the patterns *even*/ *odd* and *even*/ *not even* exist cross-linguistically, as opposed to *odd*/ *not odd*, feels of the same flavor of the above spread of examples. It is unclear to me how one might cast the pair *even/odd* in terms of antonymy or strength, however.